# Trying to set gravity modifier with script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to set the gravity modifier of an object to 2 when the mouse is clicked down, then go back down to .3 when it is released.

I think its just a simple stupid error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public float idle = .3f;

    void Start()
    {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.gravityScale = 2f;
    }
    else
    {
        rb.gravityScale = .3f;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) will only return `true` on the exact frame that the mouse button was pressed down.  This means that if you hold it down, your `else` block will run every frame other than the one it was pressed.  You can instead check for the mouse being released with [`GetMouseButtonUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) and change it back when that happens:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    rb.gravityScale = 2f;
}
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    rb.gravityScale = .3f;
}
```

or you can be more specific with your first `if` and then use an empty `else`:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    rb.gravityScale = 2f;
}
else
{
    rb.gravityScale = .3f;
}
```

[`GetMouseButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) will return `true` during any frame it's held.